# when using ?!<string> in perl regex, bash interprets it as search through command history

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, regex

Simple problem but I can't fix it.

I have the following perl regex:

`echo ... | grep -P "(?i)(v(ersion)?)\s?(?!0)\d(\.|,)\d{1,}"`

This is supposed to match every string that describes a version of something (e.g. `V2,0` or `version 1.2`). But it doesn't match when the version starts with `V0...`. However, when I execute this, I get an error `-bash: !0: event not found` because `!<string>` is used to search through command history and execute the latest hit.

This basically breaks perl regex for me. How can I avoid the shell from interpreting it as a shortcut?

Comment: Somewhat related: [bash: error in export command that bash: !st: event not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130809/bash-error-in-export-command-that-bash-st-event-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes, not double quotes, to protect your regexp from the shell.